# Making fermat's little theorem for composite numbers the ultimate test.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, primality-test

It is a programming question but mathematics has a major role to play in it.
I have to find the largest prime less than a number $n$. Note that $n\leq10^{18}$. I can go for Fermat's Little Theorem which runs in $O(\log n)$ time and then check whether the number is prime or not by checking for existence of its divisors from $2$ to $\sqrt n$. But this will take $O(\sqrt n)$ time which is way beyond the machine's capability.

So how do I make Fermat's Little Theorem ultimate i.e. what are the values I'll need to run FLT with to ensure that it is prime or composite without having to go through $O(\sqrt n)$ operations?

Comment: Are you **supposed** to use Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Yes.A O(log n) algorithm is the only feasible algorithm. In fermat's little theorem, I select a value a(<=(n-1)) and find a^(p-1) mod p. What I want is the values of a such that I am sure that the number is prime. Or any other possible solution is also acceptable.

Comment: Why do you assume that $O(10^9)$ is 'way beyond the machine's capacity', what sort of machine is this?  My machine executes $O(10^9)$ operations on a regular basis and I've run searches that did a couple of orders of magnitude more than that more than once...

Comment: What programming language do you use exactly?

Comment: There are no such values: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: I'm using python. The problem is that there are lots of n to be given as input and for each n, I need to provide the output.

Comment: Micah: So what is the alternative?

Comment: If you need absolute (not probable) primes and you really believe that trial division won't work for you, then I would go with something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality_testing , but without more details on your requirements (what does 'lots of $n$' mean?  Why are you doing this in the first place?  Have you actually _tried_ trial division and found it inadequate?) I'm really skeptical that that's not overkill. Note that since $10^{18}\lt 2^{62}$, each division is just a 64-by-32 divide, so you don't need a bignum package.

Comment: The Baillie-PSW test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie-PSW_primality_test) is known to succeed for all $n$ less than $2^{64}$, which is enough for your purposes.

Comment: I recommend the [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test which runs in $O(k\log^3 n)$ time, much faster than $O(\log n)$.